# Lost Firefox 4 window

Tags: windows, firefox, window

I'm running Firefox 4 on Windows 7, and I've lost the Window. The icon shows normally in the taskbar, the program is interactive (I can make new windows and use them fine), and I can even make new tabs and go to websites in the invisible window (I can see it in the mini-preview from mousing over the taskbar). When I type in the address bar, the completion suggestions popup appears on my main monitor in the upper-right-hand corner.

I would close and reopen the window, but I've been doing a lot of organizing in the tab-groups view and I'd hate to lose that.

Is there any way I can move the window from wherever it is hiding to somewhere where I can see it?

I have two monitors, one 1280x800 (laptop screen) and one 1280x1024 (external, over VGA), the external is on the right and raised.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>ove, and use arrow keys. (After you press an arrow key, you can move the mouse too.)

Comment: I normally does that.

Comment: I'd tried right-clicking on the taskbar mini-window and using the Move option, but I didn't know you could use the arrow keys. Thanks!

Comment: This is my favourite power-tip -- I clicked the question just so I could contribute it if it was absent. :)

Answer (score 6):

Minimize all windows other than the missing Firefox window, right-click on an empty area on the taskbar, and select "Cascade windows".  This will force Windows to rearrange any open windows onto an accessible area on the desktop.